# Possible to not lose the matched string?

Tags: regex, perl, regex-lookarounds

If I do

```
perl -i -slpe 's/$wgDBserver = "\K.*?"/$ip"/' -- -ip=$IP test
```

then I have to add the `"` on the replace side, as I do `.*?"` on the matching side, and therefore lose the `"`, and therefore have to replace it again.

**Question**

Is it possible to not having to add the `"` again my self?

Here is my test case:

```
$ IP="123.456.78.9" && \
  echo -n '\n\n$wgDBserver = "172.17.0.3";\naaa "123"\n\n\n' > test && \
  perl -i -slpe 's/$wgDBserver = "\K.*?"/$ip"/' -- -ip=$IP test && \
  cat test


$wgDBserver = "123.456.78.9";
aaa "123"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check "Look-Around Assertions" in [`perlre`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html).

Use positive lookahead`(?=)`:

> `(?=pattern)` : A zero-width positive look-ahead assertion. For example,
>   `/\w+(?=\t)/` matches a word followed by a tab, without including the
>   tab in `$&` .

```
"\K.*?(?=")
```

So, here trailing `"` will match, but will not get captured in `$&`.